# if statement and regular expressions java

Tags: java, if-statement, expression

I am trying to implement an if statement to accept any word consisting with any of the letters a-k (both upper and lower case) in Java. My input is a String.
I guess it would be something like:

```
if(input.equals("[a-kA-K]+")){
    System.out.println("the input was: $0");
}
```

but I am not sure how to do it.

Comment: What happened when you tried doing what you have above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to do something like [pattern match](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html). Example:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("a*b");
 Matcher m = p.matcher("aaaaab");
 boolean b = m.matches();
```

Then

```
if(b)
{
 //Your code.
}
```

**From @yshavit comments (which are important):**

Worth noting that the Pattern p object is immutable and thread-safe, and can be shared (e.g. by creating the Pattern once and storing it in a private static final). If you don't care about creating the Pattern each time, and you don't need access to captured groups in the regex, you can also just call the static Pattern.matches(pattern, stringToLookIn)

Comment: Worth noting that the `Pattern p` object is immutable and thread-safe, and can be shared (e.g. by creating the `Pattern` once and storing it in a `private static final`). If you don't care about creating the `Pattern` each time, and you don't need access to captured groups in the regex, you can also just call the static `Pattern.matches(pattern, stringToLookIn)`.

Answer (score 2):

If input is `String`, then you can use `input.matches("[a-kA-K]+")`.

Documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches(java.lang.String)